# GND nomenclature for high side switch

Tags: integrated-circuit, ground, datasheet, high-side

[Ref](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps281c30.pdf?ts=1682052331841&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-switches%252Fhigh-side-switches%252Fproducts.html)

1. What is the difference between device GND & board GND?
2. The term 'GND Shift' is used multiple times? Does it mean a change in GND potential from 0V to say, +x Volts?
3. Could you give an example of a 'loss of ground' scenario i.e. as to how it could occur in real life?

[image]

Comment: Do you know what Rgnd is? It's a current sense resistor. This is the disadvantage of using a low-side current sense resistor.

Comment: All I'm aware of is that it limits the current during reverse polarity conditions. Could you elaborate on the co-relation of R(gnd) with the current sensing capability of the IC?

Comment: It means that changes in current produce a form of noise, because all the signals present reference ground, but the MCU is using a ground that is a little bit different than the IC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Device GND is the pin marked "GND" on the device's data sheet.  Board GND is the circuit board track that the designer calls ground.  Usually the negative supply.
2. GND Shift is when the device GND isn't connected to the board GND, and they end up at different voltages.
3. Maybe a wire fell off the board.

Comment: So in the attached image, the board GND  would be negative Terminal of V(s)?

Comment: @Harkirat In any sensible design, yes.  But the designation of"ground" in any circuit that's not connected to Earth is actually arbitrary.